# Can't proceed to checkout - Call to a member function checkout() on null

Tags: laravel, null, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to charge a customer in my Laravel app but it keeps saying $customer is null. Any idea what's wrong?

The error:
`Call to a member function checkout() on null` refers to this line `return $customer->checkout...`

However calling `echo $id` returns the customer ID so I see no issue why `findBillable` returns a null object.

The customer does indeed exist in Stripe and hard-coding the ID doesn't change anything.

```
                    use Laravel\Cashier\Cashier;

                    $user = new App\Competitor();

                    $stripeCustomer = $user->createAsStripeCustomer([
                        'name' => $request->name,
                        'email' => $request->email,
                        'phone' => $request->phone,
                    ]);

                    $id = $user->stripeId();
                    $customer = Cashier::findBillable($id);

                    return $customer->checkout(['price_foobarfoobar' => 1], [
                        'success_url' => 'https://staging.domain.com/thank-you',
                        'cancel_url' => 'https://staging.domain.com/sign-up',
                    ]);
```

**Competitor.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

class Competitor extends Model
{
    use Billable;

    protected $table = 'competitors';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'selected_event',
        'team_name',
        'user_agent',
        'ip_address',
        'created_at',
        'stripe_transaction',
        'stripe_id',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Does the `$id` look like a valid Stripe Customer ID (`cus_123`)?  If you [look in your Stripe request logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs?method%5B%5D=get&dashboard=false&direction%5B%5D=self&direction%5B%5D=connect_in) do you see requests/errors related to fetching the Customer in question?

Comment: @Justin Michael Yep it's a valid customer ID. Copied it directly from Stripe and hardcoded it. Can't even call balance() or stripeId() because findBillable still returns a null customer. I'm using my secret key `Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));` and also there's no logs pertaining to my request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to inform Cashier I was using a different Billable model...

`Cashier::useCustomerModel(Competitor::class);`